# R: use of match.fun over sapply, lapply and mapply

Tags: r, lapply, matching, sapply, mapply

I'm not sure if my usage of match.fun is correct of not for this case. (I don't want to use for loop because it takes time).

I have a data frame like this.

```
df <- data.frame(client = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                 fun = c("bill1stEvent_OT", "bill1stEvent_Tour", "billCreation_OT", "bill1stEvent_Tour_LoadingSite"), 
                 agency = c("NA", "NA", "Agency_A", "NA"), 
                 loading_site = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "Paris"))

>df
  client                            fun    agency  loading_site
       A                bill1stEvent_OT        NA            NA
       B              bill1stEvent_Tour        NA            NA
       C                billCreation_OT  Agency_A            NA
       D  bill1stEvent_Tour_LoadingSite        NA         Paris
```

The `fun` column contains functions I created. Every function takes the same argument: `client`, `agency`, `loading_site` `year` and `month`. So the way you read this table is, for example, for the client `C`, apply function `billCreation_OT` with arguments `agency = Agency_A` and `loading_site = NULL`. Each function returns a data frame.

I have a list of clients I want to apply functions, I also set the arguments `year` and `month`. :

```
client_list <- c("A", "C")
year <- "2018"
month <- "07"
```

Question: How can I call this table and apply functions with the corresponding arguments with just "one go"? So with the `client_list` above, what I want to do is to run these two functions below and store the result(data frames) in a list(or whatever possible).

```
bill1stEvent_OT(client = "A", agency = NULL, loading_site = NULL)
billCreation_OT(client = "C", agency =  Agency_A, loading_site = NULL)
```

My attempt:

```
fun_to_apply <- df[df$client %in% client_list, ]$fun
agency_arg <- df[df$client %in% client_list, ]$agency
loading_site_arg <- df[df$client %in% client_list, ]$loading_site

sapply(X = lapply(fun_to_apply, match.fun), 
       FUN = mapply,
       year = year,
       month = month,
       agency = agency_arg,
       loading_site = loading_site_arg)

Error in (function (client, year, month) : 
 arguments inutilisés (agency = dots[[3]][[1]], loading_site = dots[[4]][[1]])
```

I also don't know how to pass to the functions arguments `agency` and `loading_site` as `NULL`. When you read the data frame it evaluates `NA` as string like `"NA"` I guess.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can be done. But there are simpler ways. Why name of the function is stored in a dataframe? Why not have 1 function with 4 possible actions based on input, then we could just do `apply(df, 1, myFun)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant. But this is just an extraction of more than 20 functions I made, and it would be too complicated if I merge them into just a single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate my "can be done" comment:

```
# inputs
client_list <- c("A", "C")
year <- "2018"
month <- "07"

# dummy functions
bill1stEvent_OT <- function(agency, loading_site){paste("11", year, month, agency, loading_site)}
bill1stEvent_Tour <- function(agency, loading_site){paste("22", year, month, agency, loading_site)}
billCreation_OT <- function(agency, loading_site){paste("33", year, month, agency, loading_site)}
bill1stEvent_Tour_LoadingSite <- function(agency, loading_site){paste("44", year, month, agency, loading_site)}


# loop through rows, match function name
apply(df, 1, function(i){
  # we can add a step to convert "NA" to actual NA.
  if(i[1] %in% client_list){
         match.fun(i[2])(agency = i[3], loading_site = i[4])
    } else {NA}
})

# [1] "11 2018 07 NA NA"       NA                       "33 2018 07 Agency_A NA" NA
```

Having shown the possible way, I would not recommend using this. There are better ways if you can tell us more about the problem.

Comment: Eventually this solved my question. instead of apply I used `lapply` with the logical vector of `unique(grep`, and used if statement to replace NA to NULL in `lapply`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Eventually you can use `mapply()` and `do.call()`:

```
D <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
"fun a b
+ 3 5
- 8 2
* 4 4
+ 1 NA"
)
myfu <- function(fun, a, b) do.call(fun, list(a=a, b=b))
mapply(myfu, D$fun, D$a, D$b)
```

or

```
unlist(Map(myfu, D$f, D$a, D$b))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be the best solution. Could you also provide me an advice about how to handle character strings `"NA"`s? I get this error. `Error in bill1stEvent_OT(agency = NA_character_, loading_site = NA_character_) : unused arguments (agency = NA, loading_site = NA)`. I want to pass them as `NULL`, not as str `"NA"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created some example functions that print the arguments:

```
bill1stEvent_OT <- function(...) {
  print("bill1stEvent_OT")
  lapply(list(...), print)
  cat("\n")
}

billCreation_OT <- function(...) {
  print("bill1stEvent_OT")
  lapply(list(...), print)
  cat("\n")
}
```

And I think what you're looking for is something like that (get is equivalent to a match.fun):

```
apply(df[df$client %in% client_list,], 1, 
      function(x) get(x["fun"])(x["agency"], x["loading_site"]))
[1] "bill1stEvent_OT"
agency 
  "NA" 
loading_site 
        "NA" 

[1] "bill1stEvent_OT"
    agency 
"Agency_A" 
loading_site 
        "NA" 

NULL
```